# GAE : rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I know you must have a question saying its a duplicate question and has been answered. But I tried all the mentioned steps "Remove duplicate datanuc jar file (I never had a duplicate jar file) and ORM src/ removal" but no luck.

1) I recently moved my app to High Replication and since then I'm getting this issue.

> Error at xxxxx.getXXX methodxxxxx class "Class com.xxxx does not seem to have been enhanced.  You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output." has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.

Any idea how can I resolve it? Jar details are at bottom most for reference.

** Above issue is in local as well as Google App server (Entity are present in cloud GAE)

2) My Ubuntu OS got corrupted recently, So had to re-install. When I tried to import my GAE project to eclipse and re-run it, I don't see my local datastores in `localhost:8888/_ah/admin`. I had a look into my `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` and `local_db.bin` both seems to have data but unable to view my Entity in local Datastores? How can I map/restore it?

#### JARS

- ognl-2.7.3.jar
- activation-1.1.jar
- appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.2.1.jar
- appengine-api-labs.jar
- appengine-endpoints.jar
- appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.2.1.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-codec-1.1.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-io-1.3.2.jar
- commons-lang-2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
- datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
- datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
- facebook-java-api-3.0.2.jar
- facebook-java-api-annotation-processor-3.0.2.jar
- facebook-java-api-schema-3.0.2.jar
- freemarker-2.3.15.jar
- geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
- geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
- jasypt-1.6.jar
- jaxb-api-2.1.jar
- jaxb-impl-2.1.9.jar
- jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
- json-20080701.jar
- jsr107cache-1.1.jar
- runtime-0.4.1.5.jar
- stax-api-1.0-2.jar
- struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
- struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
- struts2-gae-0.1.jar
- struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
- tiles-api-2.0.7.jar
- tiles-core-2.0.7.jar
- tiles-jsp-2.0.7.jar
- xwork-core-2.1.6.jar

Comment: 1.  (I use DataNucleus JDO not JPA.) Does JPA require enhancement (as JDO does)? If so, does your build process include enhancement?  2.  You might want to do a search about the .bin file, different GAE/J versions, and data visibility.